# How to set lang attribute on <html> tag in SSR mode with SvetleKit

Tags: sveltekit

I know user's preferred language in cookie and I am able to init locales with it (using server hook).
And I would like to also render correct lang attribute which matches selected locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [docs on specifically that](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/accessibility#the-lang-attribute).

> If your content is available in multiple languages, you should set the lang attribute based on the language of the current page. You can do this with SvelteKit's handle hook:
>
> `src/app.html`
>
> ```html
> <html lang="%lang%">
> ```
>
> `src/hooks.server.ts`
>
> ```js
> import type { RequestEvent, Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';
> export const handle = (({ event, resolve }) => {
>   return resolve(event, {
>     transformPageChunk: ({ html }) =>
>       html.replace('%lang%', get_lang(event))
>   });
> }) satisfies Handle;
> ```